# Defining product between table

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, code-request

For the given table, I want to make their dot product as follows.

My pseudocode is given as follows: In order to make the dot product, first the table size should be the same.

```
 A1=Table[a1[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,m}]
 B1=Table[b1[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,m}]
```

Then what I want to make is $A1.B1 = a1[1,1]*b1[1,1]+a1[1,2]*b1[1,2]+a1[1,3]+b1[1,3] + \cdots$

---

To make it work, following I made some explicit exposure:

Simply let n=2, m=3.

```
  n=2; 
  m=3; 
  AB=List[Table[a1[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,m}],Table[b1[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,m}]]
```

Then what I want to make is AB[[1]][[1]].AB[[1]][[2]]+AB[[1]][[2]]AB[[2]][[2]]

```
  AB[[1]][[1]].AB[[2]][[1]] + AB[[1]][[2]].AB[[2]][[2]]
```

so that the results

```
  a1[1, 1] b1[1, 1] + a1[1, 2] b1[1, 2] + a1[1, 3]b1[1, 3] +  a1[2, 1] b1[2, 1] + a1[2, 2] b1[2, 2] + a1[2, 3] b1[2, 3]
```

Making Huge table as AB and defining the inner product explicitly I can compute the dot product between two tables with the same size, but is there any other way? Frankly speaking, I don't want to make a Huge List and define its component sum explicitly.

Comment: `Total[A1*B1, All]`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Flatten[AB[[1]], 1] . Flatten[AB[[2]], 1]
(*a1[1, 1] b1[1, 1] + a1[1, 2] b1[1, 2] + a1[1, 3] b1[1, 3] + 
a1[2, 1] b1[2, 1] + a1[2, 2] b1[2, 2] + a1[2, 3] b1[2, 3]*)
```